# How to flatten a collection with items of array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, database

I need a result of an array that is flattenened like this:

**$result = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"];**

I have a DB result of this query:

```
    $articles = DB::table('articles')
        ->where('is_published', 'true')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('category');
```

When I do this with this result:

```
    $unflattened_array = $articles->toArray();

    dd($unflattened_array);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

And when I continue with trying to put the ones in arrays and spread then in just one big array as elements:

```
    $flattened_array = array_merge(...$unflattened_array);

    dd($unflattened_array);
```

I am getting this error message in Laravel:

```
array_merge(): Argument #1 must be of type array, string given
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want the array look like:

**["2","3","4","5","6","8","22","45","46","70","100","102","105","106","107","205"]**

Comment: I'm not a laravel person, but is the column defined as a string or JSON in eloquent?

Comment: json. Justinas's solution thankfully worked. But if you know about a solution with pure Larvel's collection methods you can post it I might try it later. Although I have tried flatten() and other things and it didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your each array element is JSON array, so you must first decode it:

```
foreach ($unflattened_array as $items) {
    array_push($flattened_array, ...json_decode($items));
}

$flattened_array = array_unique($flattened_array);
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/5bP7t)

Answer (score 0):

To provide a more laravel centric approach using collections:

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
    ->where('is_published', 'true')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('category');

// Get the unique categegory IDs from articles.
$categoryIds = $articles
    ->map(fn ($json) => json_decode($json))
    ->flatten()
    ->unique();
```

This will return the flattened unique category IDs as a collection object, which you can transform to a normal array using `->toArray()`